# Repeat lists based on length of matching column in R

Tags: r

I would like to duplicate/repeat lists based on the number of rows matching the same name in a data frame.

For example, given my list and a data frame

```
mylist <- list(A = c(1,2,5,6), B = c(2,4,6,5), C = c(2,4,2,35))

> mylist
$A
[1] 1 2 5 6

$B
[1] 2 4 6 5

$C
[1]  2  4  2 35


mydf <- as.data.frame(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"))
colnames(mydf) <- "Freq"

> mydf
  Freq
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    B
6    C
```

I would like this output where from mylist A is repeated 3 times because it has 3 rows in mydf, B is repeated 2 times because it has the next 2 rows in mydf, and C is repeated 1 time because it has the next 1 row in mydf:

```
desired.output <- list(A = c(1,2,5,6), A = c(1,2,5,6), A = c(1,2,5,6), B = c(2,4,6,5), B = c(2,4,6,5), C = c(2,4,2,35)

> desired.output
$A
[1] 1 2 5 6

$A
[1] 1 2 5 6

$A
[1] 1 2 5 6

$B
[1] 2 4 6 5

$B
[1] 2 4 6 5

$C
[1]  2  4  2 35
```

I have tried to use the `rep` function and all result in a NULL object.

```
attempt1 <- rep(mylist[[]], times=as.vector(mydf$Freq))
attempt2 <- rep(mylist[[]], times = match(mydf$Freq, names(mylist)))
attempt3 <- rep(mylist[[]], times = length(match(mydf$Freq, names(mylist))))
```

Ultimately, my goal is to have mylist contain the same number of items as mydf and where each group (A, B, C) is replicated according to their sample size in mydf.

Comment: Try `mylist[mydf$Freq]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `mydf` Frequencies data to do the selection for us

```
mylist[mydf$Freq]
$A
[1] 1 2 5 6

$A
[1] 1 2 5 6

$A
[1] 1 2 5 6

$B
[1] 2 4 6 5

$B
[1] 2 4 6 5

$C
[1]  2  4  2 35
```

Comment: Can you articulate how this works? I am trying to implement this concept to a triple nested list, and if I understand the concept you presented I can likely make it work. I am not clear on how seemingly simple subsetting can match the number of rows to repeat. You provided a very concise answer, and that bit of code is doing a lot.

Comment: @simpson Within select `[` you are simply picking the named list entry. It should be pretty clear when you do this `mylist[c("A", "A", "A", "C")]`. `mylist[mydf$Freq]` is exactly the same because R expands the column entries.